# Закрытие дочернего окна

Tags: winapi, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть главное окно, а в нем дочернее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы главное окно не закрывалось при закрытии дочернего. Как я понимаю, для каждого дочернего окна нужно регестрировать класс и создавать оконную процедуру, чтобы можно было обрабатывать их сообщения. Интернет облазил, но ничего внятного не нашел. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Закрытие дочернего окна не должно приводить автоматом к закрытию главного. Вы что-то делаете не так. Приведите релевантную часть кода.

Comment: Проблема практически решена. Как я понял, для каждого окна нужно регистрировать свой класс и оконную функцию, чтобы можно было управлять ими по отдельности.